# How to unload menus (UIViewControllers)

Tags: c#, ios, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm working on an app with which I send and receive data from and to a database.

At the moment, when I start the app in portrait or landscape position, it will always display the first menu in portrait style. When I turn the first menu, it switches to landscape just fine. I have properties in my AppDelegate to store screen width and height.

Whenever I navigate to another menu for the first time, it takes the screen width and height from the AppDelegate to draw the new menu. Every menu I navigate to does this perfectly.

The problem is, that when a menu is already loaded, I switch to another menu, turn the screen and go back to the previous menu, the layout is still in the previous screen mode. For example:

1. I start the app and get to the first menu in portrait mode. The values for screen width and height in the AppDelegate will change to the current view.bounds.
2. I navigate to menu #2 for the first time. Menu #2 will use the screen width and height in the AppDelegate to draw the menu.
3. I navigate to menu #3 for the first time. Just like Menu #2, it takes the screen width and height from the AppDelegate to draw the menu.
4. I turn the menu from portrait to landscape. Menu #3 will redraw and change the screen width and height in the AppDelegate to the new values.
5. I navigate back to menu #2, but it's still drawn as if it were in portrait mode.

Is there a way to unload the menu (that's not the obsolete method of "WillUnload" or "DidUnload")? Or is there a method that gets called every time I navigate to a menu that I already loaded in my memory?

I love to hear from you.

Love and regards,
Björn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `viewWillAppear:` method gets invoked every time the controller's
  view is about to be displayed. Whenever you make a transition to and
  fro from a controller, it would be invoked.

  From Apple's documentation([iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillAppear:)) :

  > This method is called before the receiver's view is about to be added to a view hierarchy and before any animations are configured
  >   for showing the view. You can override this method to perform custom
  >   tasks associated with displaying the view. For example, you might use
  >   this method to change the orientation or style of the status bar to
  >   coordinate with the orientation or style of the view being presented.
  >   If you override this method, you must call super at some point in
  >   your implementation.
- An another lifecycle method that you can use is `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. You can read more about it here.([iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillLayoutSubviews))